# No puedo guardar numeros par o impar en X vector

Tags: array

tengo una consulta con respecto al siguiente codigo :

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numero_inicial;

    int Npar = 0, Nimpar = 0;

    System.out.println(" Digita el numero : \n");
    numero_inicial = leer.nextInt();

    while(numero_inicial <= 20)
    {
     numero_inicial++;   

    if(numero_inicial%2==0)
    {
    Npar++;

    int [] vectorpar = new int[Npar];


    vectorpar[Npar] = numero_inicial;

    System.out.println(vectorpar[Npar]);



    }else
    {
    int [] vectorimpar = new int[Nimpar];
    Nimpar++;    


    vectorimpar[Nimpar] = numero_inicial;

    System.out.println(vectorimpar[Nimpar]);


    }

    }






}
```

Estoy haciendo un trabajo donde inicio en un numero menor a 20 y dependiendo del contador incrementara las variables Npar o Nimpar para crear espacios en los vectores y así poder guardar los números, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa e inicio desde el 1 me tira un error

Comment: Bienvenido Kenneth, podrías poner el error del código... También aclarar que solo viendo lo que hay dentro del while basta para saber que siempre que cumplas esa condición estas re-declarando una y otra vez los mismos vectores para los casos pares e impares. Ahora también darte cuenta que si declaras un vector de tamaño N, no puedes guardar información en esa posición ya que los índices de los vectores van de 0 a N-1...

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, el error que genera es el siguiente : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at javaapplication140.JavaApplication140.main(JavaApplication140.java:42)
C:\Users\Kenneth\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
en esa linea se encuentra esta parte del código : vectorpar[Npar] = numero_inicial;

Comment: Ya corregí lo de la declaración del vector, pero aun así genera el error cuando guardo el numero.

Comment: Este arror confirma lo que dije: el error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException sucede cuando manipula mal los vectores... Es el caso de los índices que te dije... Si declaras un vector de tamaño N, la última posición del vector es N-1, así que no puedes guardar información en la posición que lo estás haciendo...

Comment: Y agregar que creo que tienes un error de lógica en tu código, por lo que entiendo quieres llenar dos vectores, uno con los números pares y otro con los impares que existan del 1 al 20(según el número que dijiste en la pregunta). Pero viendo tu código, el 1 nunca se va a comparar en tu condicional porque en la primera línea del while tu variable número_inicial pasa del 1 al 2 sin hacer nada.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, finalmente pude resolverlo..